# Have pseudo border break out of parent with overflow: auto

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a horizontal/scrollable nav with gradient fades on each end. Setting the parent to `overflow: auto` almost solves my problem but hides my *active link* border, which I position absolute as a `:before` pseudo above its parent link. I was wondering if there was a way for me to keep the overflow while having my pseudo border break out of it? For the sake of this question, the gradient really doesn't matter per se but this structure needs to remain in tact.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.vertical-title {
  height: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #dceaec;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 57px;
  color: #111;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.vertical-title-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.hub-nav {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.hub-nav-link {
  position: relative;
}

.hub-nav-link.active-path:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  background-color: #007eff;
}
```

```html
<div class="hub-wrapper">
  <div class="vertical-title">
    <a href="/shopping">Page Title</a>
  </div>

  <nav class="hub-nav">
    <ul class="hub-nav-list">
      <li class="hub-nav-list-item">
        <a class="hub-nav-link active-path" href="">
          There's supposed to be a border above me!
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div>
  Content Below
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative margins will do the trick:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.vertical-title {
  height: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #dceaec;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 57px;
  color: #111;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.vertical-title-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.hub-nav {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 16px;
  margin-top: -16px;
}

.hub-nav-link {
  position: relative;
}

.hub-nav-link.active-path:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  background-color: #007eff;
}
```

```html
<div class="hub-wrapper">
  <div class="vertical-title">
    <a href="/shopping">Page Title</a>
  </div>

  <nav class="hub-nav">
    <ul class="hub-nav-list">
      <li class="hub-nav-list-item">
        <a class="hub-nav-link active-path" href="">
          There's supposed to be a border above me!
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div>
  Content Below
</div>
```

So that you don't have to look for too long - I added these two lines into your snippet:

```
.hub-nav {
    padding-top: 16px;
    margin-top: -16px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't work if there's content below.

Comment: @CarlEdwards I updated the code example with your content below. Everything looks fine, what exactly doesn't work ?

Comment: My mistake. My original code had an explicit height set on it. After removing that I got it to work. Thanks!